# Not getting data from Google Ads API

Tags: python, google-api, google-ads-api, ads-api

I follow all step of connectivity to Google Ads API. Using it I get account info like account number and time zone etc. But when I call API for campaign id or ads group at that time it return below output. In ads account (ui) I can see many campaigns.

output :

SearchPager<field_mask {  paths: "campaign.id"  paths: "ad_group.id"paths: "ad_group.name"}>

additionally : above output is getting in result variable and after that the for loop is not executing in image of[image of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3qxI.png) code

Comment: status = StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT
        details = "Request contains an invalid argument.
"errors {
  error_code {
    mutate_error: RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND
  }
  message: "Resource was not found."
  trigger {
    int64_value: 20303369476
  }
  location {
    field_path_elements {
      field_name: "operations"
      index: 0
    }
    field_path_elements {
      field_name: "create"
    }
    field_path_elements {
      field_name: "campaign"
    }
  }
}
request_id: "hufiASssqej6K3v5hX_cCg"
, 'hufiASssqej6K3v5hX_cCg')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found that in code when you enter customer_id at that time it will be of manager account. and in load_from_storage non manager account developer token and that's all. Now I can fetch all data from ads account

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).